# WordPress / WooCommerce upload media creates 19 additional image sizes

Tags: image, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce for a client website, and I'm having an issue with disk space. When an image is uploaded for a product, the system seems to be creating 19 other image sizes for the original image.
Now I know that I set a Thumnbail, Medium, Large and so on in the Media Settings and in WooCommerce settings, but I don't understand why it's creating 19 other sizes?
Here's a screenshot of an image in my wp-uploads/2014/01 folder:

[image: wp-uploads/2014/01]

As you can see, one image will take up a fair amount of space - I've got to consider that each product has at least 4 different images!

How do I reduce the amount of images that are being created?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a certain plugin or current theme is registering image sizes. Each registered image size generate an image of that particular dimensions. You need to find out which plugin or theme is doing so. Normally, that should be your theme. Look in your theme's function.php or plugin files and find function calls like this:-

```
add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300, 9999 );
```

Remove the required add_image_size function calls to avoid generating multiple copies of the image.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size